# Product attributes in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created two attributes for products in wordpress (Height and Width) having different variation in feet. Every variation has different cost. Everything is working file. My problem is variations are not displayed as drop down list rather they are displayed in the form of table like:-

Size
2ft2ft
2ft4ft

etc.

How to fix this?

Comment: when editing your product page add an attribute, set it to visible & also check variation. Now go in the variations tab and tick “enabled”, this’ll show a dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

please check this link

http://kb.oboxthemes.com/articles/woocommerce-how-to-setup-products-with-multiple-optionsvariations/

video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nw74z4UCke4

Comment: I have done all this, still have the same problem. It works on other theme. May be my theme does not support drop down.

Comment: can you specify which theme you are using ?

Comment: I am using Micra wordpress theme

Comment: please deactivate theme plugin and check is this working or not

Comment: Still have the same problem